# Strange characters in VSCode FSharp Interactive terminal

Tags: f#, mono, visual-studio-code

I try to play with fsharp under Ubuntu (and yes, I slowly figure out that it is more pain than fun), I already installed Mono, VSCode and Ionide extension and I can create and build F# projects. Unfortunately when I run simple F# script via F# Interactive:

```
printfn "bar"
```

In terminal window I get:

```
>
- printfn "bar"
-
- ;;
bar
val it : unit = () F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)
> ^?^?414;3R^?^?^?^?^?^? the Apache 2.0 Open Source License
```

The strange sequence `^?^?` looks like unrecognized terminal escape codes, but when I use bash from within VSCode there is nothing like this.

What's more the strange sequence reappears after every command executed in FSI:

```
> let j = 9;;

val j : int = 9

> printfn "foo";;
foo
val it : unit = ()
> ^?^?
```

Does anyone have the same problem and knows a solution (or maybe just knows a solution)?

EDIT: Problem occurs mostly when I execute commands via Ionide Alt+Enter shortcut

Comment: I experience the same issue, I have tried diff versions of mono and fsharp, the problem persists. The code analysis fails fairly rapidly after start up too. I think the issue is with vscode rather than purely ionide. I hope it is a quick fix.

Comment: Please file a bug on the Ionide extension: https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp

Comment: @Mr.Mr. - I think my answer to this question should work for you as well. I'm pinging you via a comment because Stack Overflow won't necessarily notify you of a new answer.

Comment: @Mr.Mr. - Although the other problem you've reported, where "the code analysis fails fairly rapidly after start up", won't be solved by the `terminal.integrated.flowControl` setting. That one is more likely to be an Ionide bug, whereas the strange characters are caused by a change in VS Code 1.9.

Comment: @Mr.Mr. - BTW, the code analysis problem you were having a couple of months ago is *probably* one that was solved in one of the latest Ionide-fsharp updates. If you're still having that problem where code analysis fails shortly after loading the F# file, try updating your Ionide-fsharp extension to the latest version available (2.25.9 as of when I'm writing this), and see if that solves it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19766 bug. VS Code 1.9 introduced a new setting, `terminal.integrated.flowControl`, that defaults to `true`. The `^?` characters you're seeing (and any `^S` and `^Q` characters that might show up) come from this "flow control" feature, which doesn't play well with F# Interactive. Change your VS Code settings to set `terminal.integrated.flowControl` to `false` and your problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks for this, it resolved it for me, kudos to you.

Comment: @rmunn thanks to people like you I really love stackoverflow!